# How to use sql function in a native query

Tags: java, mysql, entity, nativequery

I want to execute this query using native query

```
SELECT name FROM `question`
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20
```

but when executing it i'm getting thgis error

> Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query
>   [Question.findrandom: SELECT q FROM Question q ORDER BY RAND()], line
>   1, column 38: unexpected token [(].

I also have the entity created for the table question

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Order by command in sql can only be used by asc(Asending) or desc(Descending) order so
your query should be like

```
 SELECT name FROM `question`
     ORDER BY asc/desc
           LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `createNativeQuery` of `EntityManager` to create your native query:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT name FROM question ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");
```

where `em` is your `EntityManager`